# What's the difference between "worst/best case big-O()" and omega()/theta()?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

In formal discrete math and computer science we talk about "big-θ," "big-O," and "big-Ω" notation, being tight, upper, and lower bounds (respectively) on the growth of properties of an algorithm as its input grows.

I have *never* seen θ() or Ω() referred to outside of an academic context, though. Usually texts geared towards application rather than theory refer to "worst-case big-O", "best-case big-O", and "average/amortized big-O," such as [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Using_a_priority_queue_to_sort).

The former and the latter seem like equivalent concepts to me. Am I misunderstanding, or are they just two different ways of referring to the same thing?

Comment: When you say "The former and the latter" - do you refer to $\theta()$ and $\Omega()$?

Comment: No, there I'm referring to the first and second paragraphs. I do know the difference between θ() and Ω().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different concepts at play here. On one hand, you have three different ways of giving bounds to any given function: tight bounds ($\theta$), upper bounds ($O$), and lower bounds ($\Omega$).

On the other hand, you have three different ways of defining the function for the running time of an algorithm: a function that gives you the *worst-case* running time, a function that gives you the *best-case* running time, and a function that gives you the *average* running time.

In practice, as you say, we are often mostly interested in upper bounds (though tight bounds are even better if we can get them), and in worst-case running times. However, there is nothing that prevents us from speaking about for example the lower bound on the best-case running time.